# Fuzzy control library for Python

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I look for Python library for fuzzy control (fuzzy logic) which use Fuzzy Control Language. Something like jFuzzyLogic (java).
I want to use FCL files from jFuzzyLogic.
I only plan to use it for small project, but I wouldn't want to use something problematic. I have found Pyfuzzy and FuzzyPy but I don't know if they are maintained.
I have found Pyfuzzylite but author have written in Readme than "This library is NOT ready and by no means should be used.".
What should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest [skfuzzy](http://pythonhosted.org/scikit-fuzzy/), which is a:

> collection of fuzzy logic algorithms intended for use in the SciPy Stack, written in the Python computing language.

It is currently under development, so may contain some bugs, but I think it is the most up to date project. (As you said, I don't see any activity on the PyFuzzy and FuzzyPy projects since a couple of years.)
Also, with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (an implementation of Python written in Java) you will be able to use jFuzzyLogic, beacause Jython can import and use any Java class.

Comment: Thank you for response. Advice about using Jython is interesting. I have read about it and maybe I will use it.